# Unable to run program

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse for running Java Programs. Everything was going well earlier but now I'm unable to get the option "1 Java Application" when I click on "Run as" despite having zero errors in my program. Could anyone help me how to deal with it ?

```
class Base{
    public int baseVar;
    public int var;
    public Base(int v){
     baseVar=v;
     System.out.println("Base class parameterized constructor");
     }
}
class Der extends Base{
    public int derVar;
    public int var;
    public Der(int v){
        super(v);
      derVar=v;
      System.out.println("Derived class parameterized constructor");
    }
    public void display(){
      System.out.println("Base variable value="+baseVar);
      System.out.println("Derived variable value="+derVar);
    }
    public void useOfSuper(){
      var=15;
      var=20;
      System.out.println("Base variable var=" + 
                     super.var);
      System.out.println("Derived variable var="+var);
    }
}
class abc{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      Der Derobj=new Der(10);
      Derobj.display();
      Derobj.useOfSuper();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u post the screen shot or the code

Comment: What does the "Run as >" sub menu show at all? Did you change anything with your eclipse installation? Any software upgrades, any plugin installations? BTW, the option should show up even if there are compile time errors in your project.

Comment: provide more details,with this no one can help you.

Comment: Try choosing "Run Configurations" and check whether you can find "Java Application" in the tree on the left side. On which file do you click?

Comment: Could you show your code ? May you have miswritten the main call.

Comment: It shows only "Run configuration' when I select that particular program, but using the tabs, no option is there. It's working absolutely fine for other programs.

Comment: I'l put up my code here.

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse - this often solves many problems

Comment: Here it is.

class Base{
    public int baseVar;
    public int var;
    public Base(int v){
     baseVar=v;
     System.out.println("Base class parameterized constructor");
     }
}
class Der extends Base{
    public int derVar;
    public int var;
    public Der(int v){
        super(v);
      derVar=v;
      System.out.println("Derived class parameterized constructor");
    }
    public void display(){
      System.out.println("Base variable value="+baseVar);
      System.out.println("Derived variable value="+derVar);
    }

Comment: And the remaining part....

 public void useOfSuper(){
      var=15;
      var=20;
      System.out.println("Base variable var=" + 
                     super.var);
      System.out.println("Derived variable var="+var);
    }
}
class abc{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      Der Derobj=new Der(10);
      Derobj.display();
      Derobj.useOfSuper();
    }
}

Comment: Try to just "right click-> Run as" on your main method.

Comment: Edit your post and get this code in there cause as right now it's very difficult to read from a comment.

Comment: just edit your question and add code into it. here in comment we can't understand ur probelm

Comment: Replace `main(String args[])` with `main(String[] args)`

Comment: @adenoyelle This is semantically equivalent. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2: "The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both."

Comment: Harpreet there is tool when you post question to format the code to post. So please use it. You can put the code in question itself rather than in  Comment. select the code and press Ctrl+K. I faced this too earlier.

Comment: The code is there now !

Comment: @Andreas :  Thanks, I did not know.

Comment: Class needs to be public where main method is there.public class abc {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Der Derobj = new Der(10);
  Derobj.display();
  Derobj.useOfSuper();
 }

Comment: The issue is not related to the code (even though there are some potential drawbacks in this code). When I copy&paste the code as-is (and remove the `enter code here` stuff) into a new Eclipse project, I can choose "Run > Run As Java Application" and the code is running. I suspect it is an Eclipse configuration problem, as mentioned by @seb above. Please check your run configurations.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Are these in different files? If so, which file are you using when you try to run it, and exactly how are you trying to run it?

Comment: I've tried restarting Eclipse. What to do with run configurations ? Any idea ?

Comment: I've tried making the class public as well but that didn't go well too.

Comment: Finally, it has run ! Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Can you share the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your program doesn't have an appropriate `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If it does, try running it from the command line - does that work?

EDIT: As noted in comments, whether or not the presence of a `main` method affects the context menu appears to depend on the version of Eclipse. In the version I'm using at home (4.2.1) the context menu option doesn't appear unless there's a `main` method.

Comment: The menu entry does not depend on the existence of the main() method. Even when I create a new empty Java project, the "Run as Java Application" menu entry is available.

Comment: @Andreas: That's not the case on the version of Eclipse I'm using (4.2.1). If I rename `main` to `bar`, the option goes away.

Comment: Hmm, when choosing the context menu from the **Project**, the option stays - when choosing the menu from the **.java file**, it indeed disappears. Anyway, the code from OP does work (for me) in either case

Comment: @Andreas: Ah - I was talking about the context menu when you right-click within the file.

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
class abc
```

with

```
public class abc
```

I suspect that the class is private, hence you can't run it. You have to change your java name file to `abc.java` and make the `class abc public`.

Comment: class is not private here. It is at package level but to call main method as entry point class needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Your main() is in your class abc, move it into your Base and things will work (I am assuming here that all of the code you published has been placed in a single file named Base.java)

Comment: Dave this abc is not an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below. Your code is missing public identifier for class that contains main method.

```
public class abc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Der Derobj = new Der(10);
        Derobj.display();
        Derobj.useOfSuper();
    }
```

Comment: @John I am using sibgle file to keep the whole code. I have named the file as abc.java and it works. I am using Eclipse 3.7.0. Harpreet can you please check the name of your file too.

Comment: @Jon same is true for the version I am using. Bot sure if it matters with eclipse versions ( not sure about older versions)